# Budget transaction line data by fiscal period

Tags: sql-server, ssis, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Is there a relation between BudgetTransactionLine table and FiscalCalendarPeriod table?

I want to get the FiscalCalendarPeriod.shortname of each BudgetTransactionLine .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the ERD for AX 2012.  It looks like you need to go from the BudgetHeader to the BudgetCycle, which connects to the FiscalCalendarPeriod.

https://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/ax/erd/ax2012r2/

All the default relationships for the Budgeting module:

https://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/ax/erd/ax2012r2/Fky-Budget-ChildParents-11.htm

Comment: Thank you for reply.For BudgetCycle table give as startPeriod end endPeriod of year and mybe i have to pass by another table after this table to fiscalCalendarPeriod.What I have is for each  BudgetTransactionLine i have BudgetTransactionLine.DATE and for this date i want get period recID.